# I want to draw a piechart in my jsp using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have taken the code snippet from **[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwzzot0x/)**

Using this code I want to take values from my form like this:

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("country1").value;
var input2 = document.getElementById("country2").value;
var input3 = document.getElementById("country3").value;
var input4 = document.getElementById("country4").value;
var input5 = document.getElementById("country5").value; 
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Country', 'Number of risks logged'], 
  ['Austria', input1],
  ['India', input2],
  ['Belgium', input3],
  ['Germany', input4],
  ['Denmark', input5]
]);
```

and the rest remains the same. The pie chart is not visible when I run my application on server.
Can you please what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The link[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) you have posted don't have any code. Can you check it again?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong link. Please see this link. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Comment: Your code is not sufficient to reproduce the issue I guess. Post the complete javascript and HTML part as well your imported library path for `jsapi`

Comment: I added an edit with the code. I guess it would solve the problem, but whatever... https://jsfiddle.net/Lwzzot0x/